# Reading vars file with unknown keys in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a vars_file.yml that looks like this

```
mydata:
  city:
    london:
      tfl:
        taxi:
          - pounds
        tube:
          - ticket
          - oyster
    paris:
      ratp:
        taxi:
          - euro
        tube:
          - ticket
          - card
    madrid: 
      metro:
        taxi:
          - euro
        tube:
          - ticket
          - metropass
```

The cities are also the names of my hosts. Is there a way i can loop the value of the taxi/tube fields without knowing the service provider of tfl/ratp/metro? Tried something like

```
- debug:
    msg: "You can get around {{ inventory_hostname }} using the a {{ item }} on the tube"
  loop: "{{ mydata.city.{{ inventory_hostname }}.VARIABLE }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *json_query*. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Get around {{ inventory_hostname|capitalize }}
              using the {{ item }} on the tube"
      loop: "{{ mydata.city[inventory_hostname]|
                json_query('*.tube')|flatten }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: Get around London using the ticket on the tube
  msg: Get around Paris using the ticket on the tube
  msg: Get around London using the oyster on the tube
  msg: Get around Paris using the card on the tube
  msg: Get around Madrid using the ticket on the tube
  msg: Get around Madrid using the metropass on the tube
```